# Azure and local number of TCP connections are very different

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure, tcp

I'm now trying to read data from a lot of Azure blobs in parallel using Azure Function and fail to do so, because my service plan does not allow more than `~4000` TCP connections (which I get an error in the portal about), however when I try to run it locally all of the following:

- netstat with all possible flags
- Wireshark
- TCPView
- network inspector in Windows task manager

just show a couple dozens of items. Is there a tool or maybe code snippet which will allow me to emulate locally the situation that I have once my app is deployed?

Even better would be knowing if it is possible to somehow limit the number of TCP connections that my Azure Function is trying to open (using .NET Azure SDK, or Azure portal, or some settings.json file or whatever)

**Edit1**: I've rewritten the whole thing to be sequential and also I've split blob reads into chunks of `100` items, this seemed to somewhat help the number of TCP connections (it's about `500` at peak now, so still a lot, but at least fitting the app service plan, the app, of course, became slow as hell as a result), but it still tries to allocate `~4000` of "Socket handles" and fails, still can't find a way to see locally the same amount of socket handles allocated - `Handles` column is `Details` tab of windows task manager shows roughly the same amount of `handles` during the whole process execution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question itself: I wasn't able to find a way to see locally the TCP-related metrics that I get when actually running my functions in Azure. For now it feels like some important development tools and/or docs are missing. The "serverless" experience turned out be the deepest dive into Windows system programming I ever had as a .NET developer.

The solution for the problem itself was the following:
I've rewritten the whole thing to be sequential and managed it to get establishing about a hundred simultaneous connections. Then I just used binary search playing with [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx) until I found a value suitable for my plan.

Answer (score 0):

You may be bumping up against the HTTP standard implementation within HttpClient which restricts the number of open connections to 2 by default. The HTTP/1.1 specification limits the number of connections from an application to two connections per server. You can override that default using the [DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the ServicePointManager. [Microsoft has an article on it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections).

Comment: Sounds like it may increase the amount of connections instead of reducing it. Also doesn't explain why I now have `~4000` of them, when the default value for this setting is `2`

Comment: Sorry - I read that wrong. I thought you were trying to mimic prod behavior. Are you reusing HttpClient or disposing it with every call? Seeing some code would help.

Comment: I'm not using `HttpClient` directly (maybe not even using it at all, not sure how it's implemented) I use single instance of `CloudBlobClient` from Azure .NET SDK